# Joint distribution of two normal marginal distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, weak-convergence

My question is related to the possibility of stating joint convergence in distribution from marginal weak convergence.

Consider two sequences of random vectors $X_n$ and $Y_n$ defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Let $X,Y$ be other two random vectors on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$.  All random vectors take values in $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Let "$\rightarrow_d$" denote convergence in distribution.

**General statement**: $X_n\rightarrow_dX$ and $Y_n\rightarrow_dY$ does not imply $(X_n,Y_n)\rightarrow_d (X,Y)$

**Specific case**: Assume $X_n\rightarrow_dX\sim N(0,J)$, $Y_n=h^TX_n$ with $h\in \mathbb{R}^k$ and $J$ is a $k\times k$ matrix. Hence, $Y_n=h^TX_n\rightarrow_d h^TX \sim N(0,h^TJh)$. Is it correct to write down $(X_n,Y_n)\rightarrow_d(X,h^TX)$?

**Where I found this specific case**: I think it is used in the proof of Theorem 9.4 in van der Vaart "Asymptotic Statistics" p. 128 [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UEuQEM5RjWgC&pg=PA97&lpg=PA97&dq=van%20der%20vaart%20asymptotic%20statistic%20chapter%209&source=bl&ots=mnSEODb2Iy&sig=Z1IRiG3lhtoaom5IBa-8KfVTSPU&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX7Puhz9fKAhXJTBQKHUyuDzwQ6AEIJzAB#v=onepage&q=van%20der%20vaart%20asymptotic%20statistic%20chapter%209&f=false) where the author says

> "By Assumption, the sequence $(\Delta_n,h_0^T\Delta_n)$ converges in
>   distribution under $h_0=0$ to a vector $(\Delta,h^T\Delta)$... "

Did I misinterpret the proof? Any hint would be really appreciated

Comment: Consider the case $k = 1$. Then, $X_n$ and $Y_n$ being marginally normal, say $N(0,1+\frac 1n)$, does not imply that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are _jointly_ normal. So, $X_n$ and $Y_n$ can each converge to  standard normal $X$ and $Y$ but the _joint_ distribution of $(X_n,Y_n)$ does not necessarily converge to the bivariate joint normal distribution of $(X,Y)$. For many examples of marginally normal random variables that are not jointly normal, see [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30205/6633) on stats.SE.

Comment: More generally, if $X_n\to X$ in distribution and $g$ is continuous, $g(X_n)\to g(X)$ in distribution. Use this for $g(x)=(x,h^Tx)$. (Thus, normality is a red herring.)